# CDI, cdi-unit. Exception trying inject interface

Tags: java-8, cdi, junit4, cdi-unit

I test class using cdi-unit library. 
Test class:

```
@RunWith(CdiRunner.class)
public class IAktResponseMapperTest {
    @Inject
    private ITestCDI testCDI;

    @Test
    public void testCDI(){
        testCDI.testCDI();
    }
}
```

ITestCDI interface:

```
public interface ITestCDI {
    void testCDI();
}
```

TestCDI class:

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class TestCDI implements ITestCDI {
    public void testCDI() {
        System.out.println("testCDI");
    }
}
```

So, running this test I get error:

```
org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001408: Unsatisfied dependencies for type ITestCDI with qualifiers @Default
  at injection point [UnbackedAnnotatedField] @Inject private ru.nwth.pio.personal_area.accounting.mapper.IAktResponseMapperTest.testCDI
  at ru.nwth.pio.personal_area.accounting.mapper.IAktResponseMapperTest.testCDI(IAktResponseMapperTest.java:0)
```

But if I inject TestCDI class directly instead of interface ITestCDI, it's ok. How can I make interface working? Thanks for help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CDI-Unit does not scan all classes of your package, so does not know the `TestCDI` implementation of `ITestCDI`. 
You can control CDI environment with CDI-Unit using `@AdditionalClasses`, `@AdditionalPackages` or `@AdditionalClasspath` annotation.

In your case, add for example `@AdditionalClasses(TestCDI.class)` annotation :

```
@RunWith(CdiRunner.class)
@AdditionalClasses(TestCDI.class) 
public class IAktResponseMapperTest {
    @Inject
    private ITestCDI testCDI;

    @Test
    public void testCDI(){
        testCDI.testCDI();
    }
}
```